# snakes and ladders dice problems(python)

Tags: python, windows, loops, while-loop, dice

fixed it now thanks for the help, just needed to indent everything for my player 2

so i have made a snakes and ladders game and i'm having problems with the dice:

```
while player1roll != "YES":
           player1roll=input("player1 ready to roll??\n").upper
           player1roll=random.choice(dice)
           print("you rolled a:", player1roll)
```

after this it just keeps repeating "player1 ready to roll??"

here is the whole of my player1 code:

```
while selection != "PVP" or "AI":
    selection=input("player vs player(PVP) or with AI (AI)??\n").upper()

if selection == "PVP":
    while player1pos or player2pos <100:
      **while player1roll != "YES":
            player1roll=input("player1 ready to roll??\n").upper
            player1roll=random.choice(dice)
            print("you rolled a:", player1roll)**

        player1pos+=player1roll

        if board[player1pos]  >0: #if the number is bigger than 0 its a ladder
            print("you found a ladder")
            player1pos+= board[player1pos] #find the position its supposed to be at on the board
            print("player1 is at position:",player1pos)
            print("")

        elif board[player1pos] <0: #if the number is negative then its a snake
            print("you found a snake")
            player1pos+=board[player1pos] 
            print("player 1 is at position:",player1pos)
            print("")

        else:                       #if its just a 0 they stay at that position
            print("player1 is at position:",player1pos)
            print("")


        if 100<=player1pos: #if the player position is 100 or more they win
            print("player1 win")
            quit()
```

if you could suggest any other changes that would help too as i need to try and improve it as much as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset player1roll equal to NO inside of that if statement.

Comment: i forgot i was supposed to make it a while loop not an if statement when i uploaded it

Comment: it doesnt because thats what i had it at before i changed it to a if statement whoops

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it just keeps repeating "player1 ready to roll?"" is that literally the only output you are seeing? No other output?

You do realize you are setting player1roll to a random element from the the "dice" sequence, right? Does it make sense to use the same variable for the user input and the roll value?

How about changing your variable names?
Change:

```
while player1roll != "YES":
player1roll=input("player1 ready to roll??\n").upper
```

To:

```
   while player1in != "YES":
    player1in=input("player1 ready to roll??\n").upper
```

Comment: player1 ready to roll??
yes
you rolled a: 2
player1 is at position: 2

player1 ready to roll??     , is what it gives me

Comment: honestly i dont know whats going on anymore

Answer (score 0):

if the above is your code it appears there is a typo in your code.

```
player1roll=input("player1 ready to roll??\n").upper
```

is missing the ending parenthesis so it should be grabbing the function and not the "YES".

EDIT: 
in the following code player1roll is used for both player input and the rolling of dice.  This causes the die roll to override the acceptance of his turn.  If the die roll supposed to be a part of the while loop, then you should create a new variable.

```
while player1_input != "YES":
            player1_input=input("player1 ready to roll??\n").upper
            player1roll=random.choice(dice)
            print("you rolled a:", player1roll)
```

Comment: whats a parenthesis

Comment: it should be upper()

Comment: ive added that and nothings changed